# Can I subtract a cell value in another cell that already have one in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Let's say that I have two cells `A1` (*time needed*) and `B1` (*time spent*).

I want that when I enter a value in `B1` the value of `A1` will be reduced automatically.

I want that in some way I could enter in `A1` the following formula: `=A1-B1`

Is it possible in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1):

As Google Sheets does not natively support iteration with circular referencing, you will need to resort to Google Apps Script. Eg:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var editRange = e.range;
  var sheet = editRange.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && editRange.getA1Notation() == "B1")
  {
    var updateRange = sheet.getRange("A1");
    var newValue = updateRange.getValue() - e.value;
    updateRange.setValue(newValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, 
Could you please explain how to use a function in a sheet? i've saved it in the script editor. But I don't know how to let it know that it has to run on those cells. 
By the way the debug prompt an error about the `e` parameter. How should I treat it?