# How do I get Google Sheets to automatically subtract a value from one cell by entering the value in another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a budgeting spreadsheet on Google Sheets which I’d like to be able to do two things (the first, I think, is easier than the second and the first is the priority for me):

1. I write a value in, say, cell A1 of income I am expecting from a certain source that month. When all or some of that income hits my bank account, I’d like to be able to write that amount in, say, cell A2 and have it automatically subtract from what’s in A1. So say I’m expecting to earn £1000 from a certain client, I record £1000 in A1. Then I’m paid £600 (with the rest to follow later). I’d like to be able to write £600 in A2 and A1 automatically update to £400.
2. If poss I’d also like to be able to make cells A1 and A2 sum any subsequent figures I put in there and still subtract A2 from A1. So, for example, I’d like to be able to add figures over time into cell A1 and have those figures sum up. Then I’d like to be able to do the same to cell A2 and for those figures to sum up too, and then subtract from what’s in A1

So imagine I had £1000 in A1 and then I do some more work for that client and so am expecting a further £500. So I then overtype on the £1000 in A1 with “500” and the cell returns a value of £1500. Then I get paid £600 for one bit of work from the client, write £600 in A2 and A1 automatically returns a value of £900 (per the process in point 1 above). Then I earn another £400 from the client, overtype on £600 in A2 and so that cell returns a value of £1000, and A1 automatically updates with a value of £500.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also briefly explain why you included [tag:google-apps-script].

Comment: Hi Ruben, I have been looking a lot online at different ways of using the onedit function (which I presume I would have to use) but can’t find anything that works. This is the best answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67530/can-i-subtract-a-cell-value-in-another-cell-that-already-have-one-in-google-spre) but I can’t get it to work and it only helps me with my point one above. I included google-apps-script as I imagine this has to be written as script to solve (I may well be wrong!)

Comment: @Tim _but I can’t get it to work_ Would you please include the script that you wrote, and explain what part of it isn't working. I do agree that, as it stands, it doesn't address point two - but that is just a matter of duplicating and modifying the code that applies to point one.

Comment: @Tedinoz Please see below. I can get it to work in cells A1 and B1 (per the original script) but not in C15 and C29 (which is where I’d like it to work in my spreadsheet). Any help gratefully appreciated! Tim:   function onEdit(e)
{
  var editRange = e.range;
  var sheet = editRange.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Income" && editRange.getC15Notation() == "C29")
  {
    var updateRange = sheet.getRange("C15");
    var newValue = updateRange.getValue() - e.value;
    updateRange.setValue(newValue);
  }
}

Comment: Just to be clear, the following works for me but the script in the above comment does not:  function onEdit(e) { var editRange = e.range; var sheet = editRange.getSheet(); if (sheet.getName() == "Income" && editRange.getA1Notation() == "B1") { var updateRange = sheet.getRange("A1"); var newValue = updateRange.getValue() - e.value; updateRange.setValue(newValue); }

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use two cells to track the balance owing (Cell A1) and the total amounts paid (Cell2) by clients.

It should be noted this approach is fraught with danger since any mis-type may have the effect of rendering the cumulative values of Cells A1 and A2 incomprehensible.

---

**Why your script doesn't work.**

Two reasons:

- first, there can only be one `onEdit()` trigger, whereas you have two functions named `onEdit`. This is not a serious hurdle since the two functions can be easily combined. In fact they must be combined, since the a customer receipt not only updates cell A2, but also updates Cell A1.
- second, the scenario dictates that the same cell must be used for data entry as well as the cumulative balance. The value of data entry is easily determined - it is the value of the cell.
  The cumulative balance is the sum of the amount entered PLUS/MINUS the previous balance. However, depending on the transaction, it is not possible to use `getValue()` for the previous balance since `getValue()` will return only the current balance.
  Fortunately, Event Objects come to the rescue - an object named `oldValue` is available when a cell has a value prior to data entry. So the cumulative balance can be calculated as the sum of the `value` plus the `oldValue`

---

The following answer uses a simple `onEdit` trigger and `Event Objects`. At the outset, there is no value available for `oldValue`, so this is tested to determine if it is undefined; if yes, then a value of 0 (zero) is assigned.

Since the script relies on values in Cells A1 and A2, there is no way to halt the script; even deleting a value does not help.
I took the view that this was not a positive outcome, and added a test on Cell A3 - any text entered in this cell will stop the script.

---

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  
  // variables
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  // A1 = Income
  // A2 = Payments
  // A3 = enter a word here to reset the script
  var income = "A1";
  var payments = "A2";
  var endcode = "A3";
  
  // get Event Objects
  var editRange = e.range;
  var sheet = editRange.getSheet();
  
  // define ranges
  var incomeRange = sheet.getRange(income);
  var paymentsRange = sheet.getRange(payments);
  var endcodeRange = sheet.getRange(endcode);
  
  // trigger to End the code cycle
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetname && editRange.getA1Notation() === endcode){
    incomeRange.setValue("");
    paymentsRange.setValue("");
    endcodeRange.setValue("");
    //Logger.log("end the routine");
    return false;
  }
  
  // test for income
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetname && editRange.getA1Notation() === income)
  {
    //Logger.log("the edited range is "+income)
 
    // test for oldvalue = undefined
    if (typeof e.oldValue === 'undefined') {
      var OV = 0;
      //Logger.log("old value = undefined so adjusted old value = "+OV);
    }
    else
    {
      var OV = Number(e.oldValue);
      //Logger.log("old value = "+OV)
    }
    
    // test for new value = undefined
    if (typeof e.value === 'undefined'){
      var NV = 0;
      //Logger.log("new value = undefined so adjusted new value = "+NV)
    }
    else
    {
      var NV = Number(e.value);
      //Logger.log("new value = "+NV)
    }

    var newValue = OV+NV;
    //Logger.log("Summary: OV:"+OV+", plus NV:"+NV+" equals newValue:"+newValue)
    incomeRange.setValue(newValue);
    //Logger.log("updated A2");
    return false;

  } // end update income
  
   // test for payments
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetname && editRange.getA1Notation() === payments)
  {
       
    Logger.log("the edited range is "+payments)
   
    // test for oldvalue = undefined
    if (typeof e.oldValue === 'undefined') {
      var OV = 0;
      //Logger.log("old value = undefined so adjusted old value = "+OV);
    }
    else
    {
      var OV = Number(e.oldValue);
      //Logger.log("old value = "+OV)
    }
    
    // test for new value = undefined
    if (typeof e.value === 'undefined'){
      var NV = 0;
      //Logger.log("new value = undefined so adjusted new value = "+NV)
    }
    else
    {
      var NV = Number(e.value);
      //Logger.log("new value = "+NV)
    }

    var newValue = OV+NV;
    //Logger.log("Summary Payments: OV:"+OV+", plus NV:"+NV+" equals newValue:"+newValue)

    paymentsRange.setValue(newValue);
    //Logger.log("updated B2")
    
    // update Income outstanding
    var incomeValue = incomeRange.getValue();
    var adjIncome = incomeValue - NV;
    //Logger.log("Summary: income value before adjustment:"+incomeValue+", less payment value:"+NV+" equals adjIncome:"+adjIncome)
    incomeRange.setValue(adjIncome);
    //Logger.log("updated B2")
    return false;
  }
  
return false; 
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks so much!  Could I make one final request? How do I add to the code to make the same OnEdit function work in both cells A1, A2 and A3 _and_ B1, B2 and B3.  Do I just copy the full code again below and change the cell references? Tim

Comment: @Tim That's one approach; be sure to do it within the same function - do **NOT** create a second function. This would be pretty easy to code and you'll know quickly if it is working. May I ask a question in return? I'm trying to imagine a precedent for this code; not retaining the transaction history has me perplexed, since a simple typo would ruin the results with no option but to start over. What is the purpose of the code, why isn't the transaction history retained? BTW, if this answer was helpful to you, you might consider "accepting" the answer.

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much. To answer your - question, this code is for a ‘live’ table of income coming in. I then record the income for each month in a series of tables below that I use for my records (tax returns etc). Thanks again for all your help. Tim

Comment: I’ll happily ‘accept’ the answer but how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: I think I’ve done that now - please let me know if not

Comment: @Tim [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)